# Getting error in apache spark simple program

Tags: java, apache-spark

i am doing one simple example of word count in apache spark in java with reference of Internet and i m getting error of 
**Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: my.txt**
 you can see my below code for the reference!

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class MyCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String file = "hdfs://my.txt";
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "Simple App");
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(file);
    long nums = lines.count();
    System.out.println(nums);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but an answer was never accepted, the mistake at the time I read it is mixing the "local" concept of Spark with "localhost."

Using this constructor: `JavaSparkContext(java.lang.String master, java.lang.String appName)`, you would want to use:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("localhost", "Simple App");
```

but the question was using "local". Further, the HDFS filename [didn't specify a hostname](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html): `"hdfs://SomeNameNode:9000/foo/bar/"`or

```
"hdfs://host:port/absolute-path"
```

As of 1.6.2, the Javadoc for JavaSparkContext is not showing any constructor that let's you specify the cluster type directly:

> http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html

The best constructor for [JavaSparkContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html) wants a SparkConf object. To do something more readable by humans, build a SparkConf object and then pass it to JavaSparkContext, here's an example that sets the appname, specifies Kryo serializer and sets the master:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Threshold")
            //.setMaster("local[4]");
            .setMaster(getMasterString(masterName))
            .set("spark.serializer",   "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .registerKryoClasses(kryoClassArray);

    // create the JavaSparkContext now:
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

NOTE: the alternate `.setMaster("local[4]");` would use local mode, which the OP may have been trying.

I have a [more extended answer here that addresses using hostnames vs. IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34499020/3255525) and a lot more for setting up your SparkConf

Answer (score 2):

Can you try 
String file = "hdfs://localhost/my.txt"

PS: make sure you have this file *my.txt* in hdfs.
 In case if you don't have that file hdfs, follow below command to put the  file in  hdfs from local dir.

Hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/training/my.txt  hadoop/

Comment: Thanks brother for your help ! but i found the solution..
we dont have to specify the file extension in the path that's it!

Comment: Anytime mate, mark it as answer, if it could helped u

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple word count program

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import scala.Tuple2;
public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf sf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[3]").setAppName("parth");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sf);
        JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("input file path");
        JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap((new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterable<String> call(String s) { return Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")); }}));
            JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) { return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1); }
});
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) { return a + b; }
});
counts.saveAsTextFile("outputfile-path");
    }
}
```