# Spark master-machine:7077 not reachable

Tags: apache-spark, port, firewall, iptables, netstat

I have a Spark Spark cluster where the master node is also the worker node. I can't reach the master from the driver-code node, and I get the error:

`14:07:10 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master master-machine:7077`

The SparkContext in driver-code node is configured as:
`SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster(spark:master-machine//:7077);`

I can successfully `ping master-machine`, but I can't successfully `telnet master-machine 7077`.  Meaning the machine is reachable but the port is not.

What could be the issue? I have disabled Ubuntu's `ufw` firewall for both master node and node where driver code runs (client).

Comment: can you connect if you run the driver directly on the master node?

Comment: Here [Application client issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453835/apache-spark-error-could-not-connect-to-akka-tcp-sparkmaster) question. this might help you for your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is a bit off, you have:

```
setMaster(spark:master-machine//:7077)
```

You want:

```
setMaster(spark://master-machine:7077)
```

From the Spark docs:

> Once started, the master will print out a `spark://HOST:PORT URL` for
>   itself, which you can use to connect workers to it, or pass as the
>   “master” argument to SparkContext. You can also find this URL on the
>   master’s web UI, which is `http://localhost:8080` by default.

You can use an IP address in there too, I have run into issues with debian-based installs where I always have to use the IP address but that's a separate issue. An example:

```
spark.master            spark://5.6.7.8:7077
```

From a [configuration page in Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties)